# is $\sin(a)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a)}$ derived from $\sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem of $\cos(a)=t$ for $270\leq a\leq360$
$a)\cos(90+a)$
for obvious , my answer is the answer is 
$\cos(90)\cos(a)-\sin(90)\sin(a)$ and left me with 
$=-\sin(a)$
 But what is the proof $\sin(a)=\sqrt{(1-\cos^2(a)}$
My solution:
$\sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)=1$
$\sin^2(a)=1-\cos^2(a)$
$\sin(a)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a)}$ 
I have a feeling that this is false since I can't find this proof anywhere
Were this a real solution or proof to the $\sin(a)=\sqrt{(1-\cos^2(a)}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that $\sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)=1$, and therefore $\sin(a)$ is **a** square root of $1-\cos^2(a)$. But this number has **two** square roots (unless $\cos(a)=\pm1$.) So, it depends upon the sign of $\sin(a)$. If $0^\circ<a<180^\circ$, then indeed $\sin(a)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a)}$. And, if $180^\circ<a<360^\circ$, then $\sin(a)=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a)}$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, it is false. The only thing you can deduce is that
$$\sin a=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2a}$$
and the sign depends on which interval $a$ lives ($a$ is in radians):

- if $a\in[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$ for some $k\in\mathbf Z$, $\sin a \ge 0$, so you have a $+$ sign;
- if $a\in[(2k-1)\pi,2k\pi]$ for some $k\in\mathbf Z$, $\sin a \le 0$, so you have a $-$ sign.

Comment: @Gary: Thank  you for your edit!